# Why does my function crashes when called repeatedly?

Tags: c++, loops, linked-list

I'm writing a program where people can borrow books from a linked list of 5 books. They can borrow either the first or the last book. The borrowed book's title will then be stored in a file, and the node will be deleted.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    string bookname;
    node* next;
};

void menu();

node* head;
node* second;
node* third;
node* fourth;
node* tail;
node* display;
node* secondlast;
node* deletor;


void initialize()
{
    head= new node;
    second= new node;
    third= new node;
    fourth= new node;
    tail= new node;

    head->bookname = "Book1"; 
    head->next = second;

    second->bookname = "Book2";
    second->next = third;

    third->bookname = "Book3";
    third->next = fourth;

    fourth->bookname = "Book4";
    fourth->next = tail;

    tail->bookname = "Book5";
    tail->next = NULL;
}

void borrow()
{
    string temp;
    display = head;
    while (display!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<display->bookname<<endl;
        display = display->next;
    }
    // User indicates if borrowing the first or last book.
    // For this example, always borrow the last.
    // if (choice=='l'||choice=='L')
    {
        secondlast=head;
        tail=head->next;
        while (tail->next != NULL)
        {
            secondlast->next=tail;
            secondlast=tail;
            tail=tail->next;
        }

        temp=tail->bookname;
        deletor=tail;
        delete deletor;
        secondlast->next==NULL;
    }

    cout<<"Finished borrowing."<<endl;
}

void menu()
{
    borrow();
    borrow();
    borrow();
    borrow();
    borrow();
}

int main()
{
    initialize();
    menu();
}
```

If I try to borrow the last book twice, it stops. I think there's something wrong with my last node deletion but I don't know what. I want to be able to borrow all 5 books, starting from the last.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: When removing the first book, shouldn't `head` be set to `temp`? What is `second` anyway?

Comment: @cigien `second` is the second node. But I edited my question so the first book deletion is fine now

Comment: That's not the issue. You have variables whose declarations you are not showing. If we can't reproduce your error, we can't help fix it.

Comment: @cigien I saw somewhere here that told me not to copy past the whole code, only the parts that have problems. I added the menu and the initialization.

Comment: The code in `borrow` should all be relative to `head`. Don't use `second`. In fact, you don't need to *name* the nodes in a linked-list. Simply use `head` to compute them.

Comment: ***I saw somewhere here that told me not to copy past the whole code*** We don't want hundreds of lines of code if your problem can be simplified down to a compiling example that is ten lines of code. However make sure when you do simplify that the code is self contained and complete. Meaning that someone can drag the code into their favorie IDE and build the code without much effort. The documentation explains this: [mcve]

Comment: is it reproducible now? I didn't know I had to copy all these here :(

Comment: It now compiles after fixing the first 2 includes: [https://ideone.com/C65ws8](https://ideone.com/C65ws8)

Comment: That is better. I'd prefer a bit more minimal, but it's close enough for me to feel comfortable doing that.

Comment: Now that it's complete enough to compile, my compiler tells me the cause of your current problem: `warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value] secondlast->next==NULL;` (at the position of the doubled equal sign, indicating an equality comparison rather than assignment). **Always compile with warnings enabled. Always address those warnings.**

Comment: @JaMiT Thank you! I think I have my warnings enabled, as I got a warning when trying to compile the code in the answer below, but I didn't get any warning when trying to compile mine. I'm using Dev C++ 5.11. And why am I able to borrow all 5 books from first, but only 4 books from last?

Comment: @Novalcia A comment is too short to cover new questions, and I don't know where to set options like `-Wall` and `-Wextra` in Dev C++.

Answer (score 3):

https://godbolt.org/z/rRqeMy

1. **Don't use Linked Lists.** Especially not in C++. Prefer `std::vector`. It is just faster on processors produced since the 1990's. (Try to come up with a benchmark at quick-bench.com if you think you found a case where linked lists are faster.)
2. Use the provided data structures. That's why I switched your C-style implementation with `std::list`. If you have good reasons not to use the standard library, then at least make it C++ and maintain the invariants within the class. Especially don't use global variables to maintain state.
3. Separate responsibilities: `borrow` does too many things: receiving selection input from `std::cin` as well as linked-list operations as well as database maintenance. I decided that `borrow` would take the `choice` as a parameter and return the borrowed book name.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class Library {
public:
  Library() { repository_ = {"Book1", "Book2", "Book3", "Book4", "Book5"}; }
  void print_inventory() const {
    for (auto const &book : repository_) {
      std::cout << book << "\n";
    }
  }

  /** Borrow a book from the library.
  * - choice can be either 'f' (front) or 'l' (last). (Uppercase also allowed).
  * - NOTE: Will fail badly if library is empty. Change the return type to 
  * std::optional<std::string> and handle an empty library that way.
  * Instead of `choice` being a char, consider making it an enum.
  */
  std::string borrow(char choice) {
    std::string temp = "";
    if (choice == 'f' || choice == 'F') {
      temp = repository_.front();
      repository_.pop_front();
    } else if (choice == 'l' || choice == 'L') {
      temp = repository_.back();
      repository_.pop_back();
    } else {
      throw 42; // TODO: Use proper input validation!
    }
    return temp;
  }

private:
  std::list<std::string> repository_;
};

void menu(Library &lib) {
  for (char choice : {'f', 'l', 'f', 'f'}) {
    std::cout << "---------\n";
    lib.print_inventory();
    std::string borrowed = lib.borrow(choice);
    std::cout << "--\nBorrowed: " << borrowed << "\n";
  }
}

int main() {
  Library lib;
  menu(lib);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for this school  project, I have to use linked list and I/O stream. When I try to compile your code, I got a warning on line 6 `extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11` I don't know what this means.

Comment: You are using a linked list, that’s what std::list is. Also, I wrote about how to implement your own linked list in my answer (second bullet point). And my answer is using IO stream (line 1!). For the warning, go enable C++11 or higher (see my godbolt link!)